# Detect / Wait for Idle in Powershell-Script

Tags: powershell

I have something like a deployment-solution. I install some software-package in a sequence, do a reboot, install some more software-packages and so on ...

I did observe, that after such an install-sequence the system is working on some tasks. For example after installing Symantec Anti-Virus the computer has a workload for some minutes. Maybe it does a first scan or something like that. I don't know. The automated sequence forces a reboot. Sometime I see the system hanging on logoff window forcing to end the tasks ...

For a better visualisation see the screenshot of an example CPU-graph: [Performance Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbip3.png)

1. The install-sequence
2. Installation ends. Computer in idle for a few seconds
3. Workload for a few minutes

(*) *Sorry, the Graph is not authentic. Just for visualization.*

I am looking for a PowerShell-solution to detect idle. After installing the last software package I want to run this and it should wait, till the computer is ready.

It should be dynamic - I don't want to use things like ...

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 300
```

... and hope, that the tasks have ended.

It should not depend on a process-name or something like that.

**EDIT #1:**

Based on your comments I did create the following code as a first test:

```
$Start = Get-Date

do {

    $LoadPercentage = Get-Counter -Counter "\prozessor(_total)\prozessorzeit (%)" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 5 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CounterSamples | Group-Object -Property InstanceName | `
                  ForEach-Object { 
                    $_ | Select-Object -Property @{ n='Average'; e={ [math]::Round( ( $_.Group.CookedValue | Measure-Object -Average ).Average, 1 ) } };
                  } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Average

   $LoadPercentage

} until ( ( $LoadPercentage -lt 15 ) -or ( ( Get-Date ) -gt $Start.AddMinutes(1) ) )
```

- I don't like, that the "Get-Counter" cmdlet is not culture-neutral and I don't want to use a lot of code to workaround that. (like [this](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/07/19/querying-performance-counters-from-powershell/))
- Is the counter "*\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time*" the best for this scenario?
- Would I get this counter with "Get-CimInstance" too?
- Should systems with multiple CPU-cores (e.g. 16 cores) be treated different?
- Any Improvements based on my request?

Thank you

Comment: you could make a series of calls with Get-Counter or with CMI/WMI to grab the system load. take one every 30 seconds or so until the load drops below threshold and stays there.

Comment: Do you want to post an example? Maybe it would be more precise, to have something like a load-average below X of some seconds?

Comment: this is from the 2nd example in `Get-Help Ge-Counter -Example` >>> `Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3` <<< ///// i presume that you could loop that in a `do/until` until the number is always below your threshold.

Comment: You need to use a `DO/While` loop and check the status every 1 sec may be to see if it has ended or not. If not, then `start-sleep -s 1`. In that way, the sleep is very much relative to the time the task is taking to get ended.

Comment: Also if you are installing software packages in sequence why would you not want it to look at the process-name list? If you know what softwares you're installing it should also provide you with what the process will be when it runs on your OS.

Comment: @RileyCarney Because this should ideally be universal and not specific to a software package.

Comment: @DukeDonnovan I understand the point in making the script work generically but if you have the information of what you're installing it seems silly to me to not use that information and add complexity to the script instead.